# execute trigger after one hour Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g, eventtrigger

I am trying to write a trigger. The requirement is that whenever there is an update on ticket_status column of ticketing_table, I need to get the column value changed (status changed) from 'Working' to 'Completed' after exactly one hour. I am not sure if trigger is the best way to do this. Need some advise if creating trigger is the only way - if yes, then how do we specify time interval to meet such a requirement? Any help would be appreciated . Thanks.

```
create or replace TRIGGER update_status_trigger 
  after UPDATE of ticket_status ON ticketing_Table
  for each row
  when (new.ticket_status = 'Working')
  BEGIN
  :new.ticket_status := 'Completed';
  END;
```

Comment: No, a trigger is not the way to do this.

Comment: hmm...I was of the same opinion. But then how do I achieve this functionality? Should I introduce something similar to sleep in the trigger that I am creating?

Comment: create an Oracle job. Set the timer to repeat the job every few minutes. In the job just update their status of each 'Working' row with the date earlier than 1 hour. A one-liner

Comment: Create a job using DBMS_JOB from the trigger. The advantage of this is that if the original update is not committed or is rolled back, the job will also be rolled back and won't execute.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(JOB_NAME => 'MY_JOB_' || to_char(systimestamp), --should be unique for each call 
                          JOB_TYPE      => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                          JOB_ACTION    => 'BEGIN
                                                UPDATE ....;
                                            END;',
                          ENABLED       => TRUE,
                          AUTO_DROP     => TRUE,
                          start_date    => sysdate + 1/24,
                          repeat_interval=>null
                          );
```

This piece of code will create a job, which will be launched in 1 hour after create and then deleted

Comment: it is a good option. I had that in mind. But then I do not have the privilege to do this. I am still thinking if there is any other way to do this. Of course, I agree this is the best way.